# How to calculate $ \intop_{B_{R}\left(0\right)}\left(\frac{|y|^{7}}{|x-y|}-\frac{|y|^{7}}{|\frac{R}{|x|}x-\frac{|x|}{R}y|}\right)dy $

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $ R>0 $, and consider the 3 dimensional ball with radius $R $ and center at $(0,0,0)$, $B_R(0)$.

How do I calculate

$ \intop_{B_{R}\left(0\right)}\left(\frac{|y|^{7}}{|x-y|}-\frac{|y|^{7}}{|\frac{R}{|x|}x-\frac{|x|}{R}y|}\right)dy $

When $ x=\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right),\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace y=\left(y_{1},y_{2},y_{3}\right),\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace dy=dy_{1}dy_{2}dy_{3} $

**Background**

Im trying to solve the following Laplace problem:

$ \begin{cases}
\varDelta u\left(x\right)=-|x|^{7} & \forall\left(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}\right)\in B_{R}\left(0\right)\\
u\left(x\right)=0 & \forall\partial B_{R}\left(0\right)
\end{cases} $

And in our lectures we got an expression for $ u(x) $ in such case using its Green function, and it is given by

$ u\left(x\right)=\intop_{B_{R}\left(0\right)}\left(E_{N}\left(x,y\right)-E_{N}\left(\frac{R}{|x|}x,\frac{|x|}{R}y\right)\right)\varDelta u\left(y\right)dy $

Where

$ E_{N}\left(x,y\right)=\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{\left(N-2\right)|S^{N-1}|}\cdot\frac{1}{|x-y|^{N-2}} & \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{N},y\in\mathbb{R}^{N}:x\neq y\end{cases} $

and $ S^{N-1} $ is the area of $N-1$ dimensional unit sphere.

If you use the formula you get the integral that I asked about.

Im not sure how to solve it, any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Big hint: $\Delta |x|^9= 9(7+N)|x|^7$, now just adjust the boundary values.

Comment: Is there a way to solve without guessing the solution?

Comment: Probably using that your forcing term $|x|^7$ is radial, to reduce the Poisson equation to the ODE $\partial_r^2 u(r)+\frac{N-1}{r}\partial_r u = r^7$, $u(R)=0$.